# CTP is a meta tag, isn't it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

As I wander through [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) and related on SO, I am seeing things tagged [ctp](/questions/tagged/ctp). A quick look through the questions tagged with that reveals the dogs breakfast you would expect: the newest 20 or so are related to the C#/VB Async CTP, some are the Windows 8 developer preview (of Windows itself and/or Visual Studio), and then it switches to a PHP CTP, and so on. There also seems to be a file type in there, but it's drowned out by people sticking [ctp](/questions/tagged/ctp) on much as they used to stick year and version numbers on.

Should we just hand-edit the tag off silently? Add a comment saying not to tag like that? Burninate the tag, which if I understand correctly means not editing and bumping, because the burnination will remove them for us?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with that tag is that it is used with different meanings that are not related to each other; as you reported, it could be used in relation with Microsoft software (as acronym for *Community Technology Preview*), or in relation with the extension used by CakePHP for some files it uses.

In these cases, it should be decided a use for the tag, which is then reflected in the tag wiki, and the tag should not be used for any other purposes.
If it decided that the tag is used for *Community Technology Preview* software, then the tag used for the CakePHP files could be [cakephp-ctp](/questions/tagged/cakephp-ctp), for example.
I agree that it doesn't make sense to use [ctp](/questions/tagged/ctp) for unrelated questions that are referring to preview releases of different products. Probably it makes more sense to use [ctp](/questions/tagged/ctp) for CakePHP question, but I would prefer using a better tag that avoids any ambiguity; for example, [cakephp-views](/questions/tagged/cakephp-views) is a better candidate, if CakePHP uses the ".ctp" extension for its view templates, and if the term *views* doesn't have another meaning, on CakePHP.

Comment: even when it's Microsoft software, I see no value in lumping Entity Framework CTP questions with C# 5 CTP questions. That's why I think it's a meta tag that should probably be banned.

Comment: I expanded my answer, as I was first focusing on the fact the tag is used for two different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to just retag them.  For example, most of the posts tagged [asynchronous](/questions/tagged/asynchronous) and [ctp](/questions/tagged/ctp) can be retagged to [async-ctp](/questions/tagged/async-ctp) in place of those two tags (many users tend to tag like [async](/questions/tagged/async) [ctp](/questions/tagged/ctp)).

The term CTP usually stands for Community Technology Preview, which Microsoft uses to name prerelease versions of products intended for software developers.

Comment: not sure I'm ok with 50+ questions getting bumped by hand-retags.

Comment: It's only about 27 questions last I checked.  If it were much more than that I would agree however.

Comment: Not only. It also stands for [files used by CakePHP, a protocol for wireless networking and a testing program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTP). Especially the first two could (and maybe did) show up on SO.

Comment: I've just retagged four or five. If people just do that number at a time then it shouldn't swamp the home page